# Obfuscate the Android Library AAR

Tags: android, android-library, android-proguard, aar

I have red lot of answers on obfuscating the library (AAR).

There is no clear and step by step way.

As a beginner, i cant able to follow it up.

Could anyone please send the step by step procedure to obfuscate the android library. or which is the best way to obfuscate the android library.